# How to show the number of ways of distributing items in set $M$ into containers set $C$ is the same as the number of functions from $M$ to $C$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I have a set $M$ of $m$ distinct items and set $C$ of $c$ distinct containers. I think I have to show a bijection for this but I'm not sure how?

Comment: map the item in $M$ to the container in $C$ to which it gets distributed

Answer (score 0):

Well, it will be a bijection only if $m=c$. In my attempt I've made two cases: one-one and onto function.

**Case 1**: One-one function.

If $M$ and $C$ are finite sets having $m$ and $c$ elements respectively such that $m\le c$, then to define a one-one function from $M\rightarrow C$, we have to relate $m$ elements in $M$ to $c$ distinct elements in $C$.

For this, we first select m elements out of $c$ elements in $C$. This can be done in $^cC_m$ ways. Now, we relate m elements in $M$ to distinct selected elements in $C$ which can be done in $m!$ ways.

Therefore, total number of one-one functions from $M\rightarrow C$ is $^cC_m\times m!$. If $m>c$, then it is not possible to define a one-one function from $M\rightarrow C$. Thus, we have number of one-one functions from $M\rightarrow C$ 
$$=\begin{cases}
^cC_m\times m! & \quad m\le c\\
0 & \quad m>c
\end{cases}$$

**Case 2**: Onto function

If $M$ and $C$ are two sets having $m$ and $c$ elements respectively such that $1\le c\le m$, then the number of onto functions from $A\to B$ is equal to the

Coefficient of $x^m$ in $m!(e^x-1)^c$

$\begin{align}
&=m! \times\text{Coeff. of} \;x^m \;\text{in} \;(e^x-1)^c\\
&=m!\times\text{Coeff. of} \;x^m\; \text{in} \sum_{r=0}^c {^cC_r}(e^x)^r(-1)^{c-r}\\
&=m!\times\text{Coeff. of} \;x^m \;\text{in} \sum_{r=0}^c {^cC_r}(-1)^{c-r}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(rx)^k}{k!}\right)\\
&=m! \times \sum_{r=0}^c {^cC_r}(-1)^{c-r}\frac{r^m}{m!}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^c {^cC_r}(-1)^{c-r}r^m
\end{align}$

Now, we can conclude that for bijection $m$ should be equal $c$.